# strings.Split() seems to escape at [] and move on (no error)

Tags: go

I'm splitting strings from this format:

`"I[07-06|19:56:12.407] Added to precommit                           module=consensus vote="Vote{2:8FD0F8F1E2FA 1/00/2(Precommit) D7D7C52037F0 /E305561D4A6C.../}" precommits="VoteSet{H:1 R:0 T:2 +2/3:<nil> BA{4:__X_} map[]}"`

Like this:

`descripParse := strings.Split(string, "module")`

When I use a string like the one above:

`descripParse[1] == "=consensus vote="Vote{2:8FD0F8F1E2FA 1/00/2(Precommit) D7D7C52037F0 /E305561D4A6C.../}" precommits="VoteSet{H:1 R:0 T:2 +2/3:<nil> BA{4:__X_} map"`

You'll notice that everything after and including [] is gone.  This is bad, but what's much worse is when the [] occurs in the line prior to "module", like this:

`"I[07-06|19:56:12.637] Added to lastPrecommits: VoteSet{H:2 R:0 T:2 +2/3:DAF77215090623803CB9715FFD98F58E24A37252:1:C10362D25921 BA{4:XXXX} map[]} module=consensus"`

Here, if I query for `descripParse[1]`, my program panics:

`panic: runtime error: index out of range`

because the split point occurs after the [], and:

`descripParse[0] == "I[07-06|19:56:12.637] Added to lastPrecommits: VoteSet{H:2 R:0 T:2 +2/3:DAF77215090623803CB9715FFD98F58E24A37252:1:C10362D25921 BA{4:XXXX} map"`

What's happening?

Comment: Not reproducible: https://play.golang.org/p/pneldkIOVF https://play.golang.org/p/mQcO0FG-IA

Answer (score 0):

Because there are special characters within the string you must use the backtick (`) character to define the string not the double quote (`"`) character

For more on this topic checkout string literals in the language specifications
https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_literals

Here is a little piece of demo code which works:
https://play.golang.org/p/Bf70i5u3MO

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    str := `I[07-06|19:56:12.407] Added to precommit                           module=consensus vote="Vote{2:8FD0F8F1E2FA 1/00/2(Precommit) D7D7C52037F0 /E305561D4A6C.../}" precommits="VoteSet{H:1 R:0 T:2 +2/3:<nil> BA{4:__X_} map[]}`
    fmt.Println(str)
    descripParse := strings.Split(str, "module")
    fmt.Println(len(descripParse))
    fmt.Println(descripParse)

    if descripParse[1] == `=consensus vote="Vote{2:8FD0F8F1E2FA 1/00/2(Precommit) D7D7C52037F0 /E305561D4A6C.../}" precommits="VoteSet{H:1 R:0 T:2 +2/3:<nil> BA{4:__X_} map[]}` {
        fmt.Println("WOOHOO!")
    } else {
        fmt.Println(descripParse[1])
    }
}
```